# New frontend to perl application

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm wondering if there is an easy and elegant way to replace only the frontend of a perl application by exposing my CGI scripts as rest services.

Nowdays I have an application with several CGI scripts. The idea is remove perl at all but while I can't do that, I'm looking for alternatives to replace only the templates.

My idea is to expose my CGI's like if they were APIs and I'll have pure Javascript applications that consume those "APIs".

Has anyone experienced anything like this?

Comment: You're going to run Javascript on the server?

Comment: Initially no, unless it's strictly necessary.

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/jhthorsen/mojolicious-plugin-cgi